# C#. Entity Framework Core. Add entity that has related entities with same Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I try to save a `Schedule` entity in my database:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; } = new List<Session>();
}

public class Session
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Time { get; set; }

    int ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Schedule Schedule { get; set; }

    int FilmId { get; set; }
    public virtual Film Film { get; set; }
}
```

**UPD**

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody] Schedule schedule)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false });
    }
    _context.Add(schedule);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Json(new { success = true, model = schedule });
}
```

Example if input data:

```
{
    "Schedule": {
        "Id": 0,
        "Date": "10.06.2023",
        "Sessions": [
            {
                "Id": 0,
                "Time": "10:00",
                "ScheduleId": 0,
                "FilmId": 11,
                "Film": {
                    "Id": 11,
                    "Name": "Q1"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": 0,
                "Time": "12:00",
                "ScheduleId": 0,
                "FilmId": 11,
                "Film": {
                    "Id": 11,
                    "Name": "Q1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Every `Session` has related `Film` entity.

It is possible to have same film (same Id) several times during day, but in different time.

When I save `Schedule` I get an error

> Instance with the key value is already being tracked

I can iterate through `sessions` and do either

Option #1:

```
_context.Entry(session.Film).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Option #2:

```
session.Film = null;
```

Maybe there is yet a better way?

Comment: When you have films at different times, are these multiple "sessions"? Do sessions contain the times?

Comment: I added Session class in description. Every session contains only one film. During day we can have few sessions and sometimes they contain same film (on different time).

Comment: It is simplified classes

Comment: Show how you add sessions to schedule.

Comment: @alfredo you should clarify your question. We have no information about the way you configured the relationship between `File` and `Session`.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are doing when you get the error. What code produces this error?

Comment: @RezaNoei Relationship between Film and Session you can see in Session class. 
Film is independent entity and doesn't reference any other entity.

Comment: @topsail Sorry, that is important part of code. I added controller method that performs add operation.

Comment: @alfredo I would like to see this in your configurations `builder.Entity<Session>().HasOne(P => Film).WithMany().HasForeignKey(P => P.FilmId)`. It is not a `One-To-One` relationship, it's `One-to-Many`.

Comment: Just as an fyi this type of error can also occur when you have some long-running instance of your dbcontext in your application. DBContext are meant to be short-lived (for example, to be used for one request in your controller). If your DBContext is being used for a long time by many methods it gets crowded with lots of entities being tracked and this is not how EF is meant to work.

Comment: @RezaNoei that is right, `one-to-many` relationship.  Configuration looks like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

The options you mentioned, detaching the Film entity or setting it to null, can work, but they might have some side effects or limitations. Detaching the entity will cause it to be treated as a new entity when saving changes, potentially leading to duplicates or unexpected behavior. Setting it to null might not be ideal if you actually want to associate the Session with a Film.

Actually, you can write a simple method like:

```
public void SaveSchedule(Schedule schedule)
{
    foreach (var session in schedule.Sessions)
    {
        var existingFilm = _context.Films.Find(session.FilmId);
        if (existingFilm != null)
        {
            session.Film = existingFilm;
        }
        else
        {
            // The Film entity is not being tracked, so add it to the context.
            _context.Films.Add(session.Film);
        }
    }

    // Now save the schedule with its associated sessions and films.
    _context.Schedules.Add(schedule);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. If I correctly understand your code, you repopulate session.Film if a film exists in db. But any film at the point of invocation of SaveSchedule method is already exists in db.